# Forcing Excel to update a calculation

Tags: excel

My project has an import feature which will fill in information into my sheet which isn't directly related to this issue. B20 is a drop down box that the user selects. C20 has the formula `=IF(B20<>"",CoFunction(B20),"")` which contains a custom function which runs after the user selects something in B20.

My issue is after the user imports this information it fills in all of the information correctly, but the value in C20 doesn't update. The custom function doesn't run.

I've tried numerous solutions to get it to calculate and the only thing that works is by activating the sheet and then setting the value of B20 to itself. My question is if anyone knows of a better way to do this. It can also be manually done by selecting the desired value in B20.

[image]

```
Function COFunction(range1 As Range)
'Application.Volatile

If InStr(range1, "Panel") Then
COFunction = [VLOOKUP(B20,'Quote Sheet'!B13:C23,2,0) - 'Quote Sheet'!E50]
Exit Function
Else
Address = Replace(range1, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) 'Chr(34) is a double quote (")
COFunction = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(""" & Address & """, 'Prices'!A15:B150,2,0)")
Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I added it to the main post.

Comment: How specifically is `B20` updated?

Comment: The if statement in C20 evaluates B20. When B20 changes, the function called by C20 updates the value of C20.

Comment: My question was more about how `B20` is updated - programmatically, by user selection, etc? Perhaps you could describe your import feature more or share a snippet of code, if relevant. Otherwise it's hard to exactly replicate the issue.

Comment: Sure, I misunderstood. When updated by user selection it works as expected. When imported by the user programmably with the import button is when I have this issue.

The import sub takes a bunch of information from my SQL database and puts it in various sheets. In this case, the line for B20 looks like.

`Worksheets("Change order 1").Range("B20").Value = rs2!CO1_Addition1_Name`

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: press `F9` after your data import operation has been completed (to force Excel to recalculate all cells with formulas).

Cleaner solution: add the line `Application.Calculate` at the end of the VBA subroutine that does the data import operation.

Comment: Application.Calculate is one of the things I've tried. I also tried recalculating just the sheet. I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: @Zach I noticed that you have the line `Application.Volatile` in your `COFunction` function, but commented out. Does the updating work when you have this `Application.Volatile` enabled?

Comment: it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My B20 in the vlookup wasn't pointing to a specific sheet. Once I changed this it worked properly. Thanks for the advice everyone.